Twilio - Phone is hang up after I play music
I have integrated Twilio with Dialogflow CX, now there is a particular page in Dialogflow CX that calls a webhook. It might take around 10-20 seconds to receive response from this webhook, till then I want to play some music.
I tried following approach:

I called TwiML bin that plays the music.
Then I processed the request.
I called another TwiML bin that pause the music.

Eg of code:
play_music()
time.sleep(10)
pause_music()


play_music() calls the following TwiML bin:
<Response>
  <Play>https://link/to/my/sound.wav</Play>
</Response>


pause_music() calls the following TwiML bin:
<Response>
    <Pause/>
</Response>

The music starts playing as expected, then the request is processed and after that the music is paused. But now after the music is paused, the call is hangup. Please provide some suggestions for this. I have also tried Enqueue the call, but the same problem occurs when I remove the call out of Queue.
